# Using Finagle for simple Scala SOAP client

Tags: scala, soap, finagle

I'm struggling to use Twitter's Finagle library to implement an HTTP request to a SOAP server.

The code below executes the first test successfully (using 
java.net.URL), but I'm having a hard time with the second test (using 
Finagle client). What am I doing wrong?

Also, I keep being dragged into and imperative style of writing. If 
you could help me make the Finagle bit more 'scala' like, I will be 
extremely grateful.

Here goes:

```
import java.net.InetSocketAddress 
import scala.xml.{Elem, XML} 
import org.jboss.netty.buffer.ChannelBuffers 
import org.jboss.netty.util.CharsetUtil.UTF_8 
import com.twitter.finagle.Service; 
import com.twitter.finagle.builder.ClientBuilder; 
import com.twitter.finagle.http.Http; 
import org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http._ 

class SoapClient { 
  private def error(msg: String) = { 
    println("SoapClient error: " + msg) 
  } 

  def wrap(xml: Elem): String = { 
    val buf = new StringBuilder 
    buf.append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone= 
\"no\"?>\n") 
    buf.append("<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http:// 
schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n") 
    buf.append("<SOAP-ENV:Body>\n") 
    buf.append(xml.toString) 
    buf.append("\n</SOAP-ENV:Body>\n") 
    buf.append("</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>\n") 
    buf.toString 
  } 

  def sendWithJavaNetURL(host: String, req: Elem): Option[Elem] = { 
    val url = new java.net.URL(host) 
    val outs = wrap(req).getBytes 
    val conn = 
url.openConnection.asInstanceOf[java.net.HttpURLConnection] 
    try { 
      conn.setRequestMethod("POST") 
      conn.setDoOutput(true) 
      conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", outs.length.toString) 
      conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml") 
      conn.getOutputStream.write(outs) 
      conn.getOutputStream.close 
      Some(XML.load(conn.getInputStream)) 
    } 
    catch { 
      case e: Exception => error("post: " + e) 
      error("post:" + 
scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(conn.getErrorStream).mkString) 
      None 
    } 
  } 

  def sendWithFinagle(host: String, path: String, req: Elem) = { 
    val clientService: Service[HttpRequest, HttpResponse] = 
ClientBuilder() 
      .codec(Http()) 
      .hosts(new InetSocketAddress(host, 80)) 
      .hostConnectionLimit(1) 
      .build() 
    val request: HttpRequest = new 
DefaultHttpRequest(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpMethod.POST, "/") 
    val soapPacket: String = wrap(req) 
    request.setContent(ChannelBuffers.copiedBuffer(soapPacket, UTF_8)) 
    request.setHeader("Content-Lenght", soapPacket.length()) 
    request.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml") 
    request.setUri("path") 
    val client = clientService(request) 
    val response = client.get() 
    println(response) 
  } 
} 

object SoapTest { 

  def testWithJavaNetURL { 
    val host = "https://apitest.authorize.net/soap/v1/Service.asmx" 
    val req = <IsAlive xmlns="https://api.authorize.net/soap/v1/"/> 
    val cli = new SoapClient 
    println("##### Test with Java Net URL: request:\n" + 
cli.wrap(req)) 
    val resp = cli.sendWithJavaNetURL(host, req) 
    if (resp.isDefined) { 
      println("##### response:\n" + resp.get.toString) 
    } 
  } 

  def testWithFinagle { 
    val host = "apitest.authorize.net" 
    val path = "/soap/v1/Service.asmx" 
    val req = <IsAlive xmlns="https://api.authorize.net/soap/v1/"/> 
    val cli = new SoapClient 
    println("##### Test with Finagle: request:\n" + cli.wrap(req)) 
    cli.sendWithFinagle(host, path, req) 
  } 

  def main(args: Array[String]) { 
    testWithJavaNetURL 
    testWithFinagle 
  }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Jean-Phillippe, from the [Finagles forum](http://groups.google.com/group/finaglers), kindly supplied an [answer on github](https://gist.github.com/1827065)

Here is the full working and nicely updated code:

```
import java.net.InetSocketAddress
import scala.xml.{Elem, XML}
import org.jboss.netty.buffer.ChannelBuffers
import org.jboss.netty.util.CharsetUtil.UTF_8
import com.twitter.finagle.Service;
import com.twitter.finagle.builder.ClientBuilder;
import com.twitter.finagle.http.{Http, RequestBuilder};
import org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http._
import org.jboss.netty.buffer.ChannelBuffers.wrappedBuffer
import java.net.URL
class SoapClient {
  private def error(msg: String) = {
    println("SoapClient error: " + msg)
  }
  def wrap(xml: Elem): String = {
    val wrapper = <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                <SOAP-ENV:Body>
                  {xml}
                </SOAP-ENV:Body>
              </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
    wrapper.toString
  }
  def sendWithJavaNetURL(host: String, req: Elem): Option[Elem] = {
    val url = new java.net.URL(host)
    val outs = wrap(req).getBytes
    val conn =
url.openConnection.asInstanceOf[java.net.HttpURLConnection]
    try {
      conn.setRequestMethod("POST")
      conn.setDoOutput(true)
      conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", outs.length.toString)
      conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml")
      conn.getOutputStream.write(outs)
      conn.getOutputStream.close
      Some(XML.load(conn.getInputStream))
    }
    catch {
      case e: Exception => error("post: " + e)
      error("post:" +
scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(conn.getErrorStream).mkString)
      None
    }
  }
  def sendWithFinagle(host: String, path: String, req: Elem) = {
    val clientService: Service[HttpRequest, HttpResponse] =
ClientBuilder()
      .codec(Http())
      .hosts(new InetSocketAddress(host, 443))
      .tls(host)
      .hostConnectionLimit(1)
      .build()
    val payload = wrap(req).getBytes("UTF-8")
    val request: HttpRequest = RequestBuilder().url(new URL("https", host, 443, path))
                                                .setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml")
                                                .setHeader("Content-Length", payload.length.toString)
                                                .buildPost(wrappedBuffer(payload))

    val client = clientService(request)

    for(response <- client) {
      println(response)
      println(response.getContent.toString("UTF-8"))
    }
    // val response = client.get()
  }
}

object SoapTest {
  def testWithJavaNetURL {
    val host = "https://apitest.authorize.net/soap/v1/Service.asmx"
    val req = <IsAlive xmlns="https://api.authorize.net/soap/v1/"/>
    val cli = new SoapClient
    println("##### Test with Java Net URL: request:\n" +
cli.wrap(req))
    val resp = cli.sendWithJavaNetURL(host, req)
    if (resp.isDefined) {
      println("##### response:\n" + resp.get.toString)
    }
  }
  def testWithFinagle {
    val host = "apitest.authorize.net"
    val path = "/soap/v1/Service.asmx"
    val req = <IsAlive xmlns="https://api.authorize.net/soap/v1/"/>
    val cli = new SoapClient
    println("##### Test with Finagle: request:\n" + cli.wrap(req))
    cli.sendWithFinagle(host, path, req)
  }
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    testWithJavaNetURL
    testWithFinagle
  }
}

SoapTest.main(Array[String]())
```